# Sweet Alert 2 redirect on CANCEL

Tags: laravel, sweetalert2

I am writing a project in laravel, at my current point in the workflow I want the user to be able to click a button to publish or remove an event from the current list.

I am using SA2 to stop the submission to the route before it happens, if the user hits OK, then everything goes as planned, when the user hits cancel, I want to redirect back to the page.

The issue I am running in to is that when the user hits cancel, the redirect to the page happens anyway...

```
function warnRemove(linkURL) {
    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: 'D6B55',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, remove it!'
    }).then(function () {
        window.location = linkURL;
    });
}

function warnPublish(linkURL) {
    swal({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        type: 'warning',
        text: 'This event will go live on the screen after next refresh.',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: 'D6B55',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, publish it!'
    }).then(function () {
        window.location = linkURL;
    });
}



$('.remove').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the href from redirecting directly
    let linkURL = $(this).attr("href");
    warnRemove(linkURL);
});

$('.publish').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the href from redirecting directly
    let linkURL = $(this).attr("href");
    warnPublish(linkURL);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the callback with an isConfirm boolean:

```
function(isConfirm) {
    if (isConfirm) {
        // do confirmed things
    }
}
```

From the docs:

```
swal({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then((result) => {
  // redirect only if true
  if (result.value) {
    // redirect here
  }
})
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, the isConfirm no longer works with SA2, but the bottom chunk did the trick!